# Disable page bounce effect in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

This has been annoying me since it was introduced. That inch of bounce you get when using the mouse scroll wheel and reaching the bottom or top of a page.

I'm hoping there's a hidden setting somewhere... please make it stop.

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb/reviews?hl=en

Comment: I've never seen this behavior. It's probably some extension, as @mawcsco suggested.

Comment: Embarrassing... I installed the Smooth Scroller extension years ago and forgot about it. Never re-installed it after rebuilding my machine a couple of times since but of course Chrome just re-installs your extensions when you log in. Disabled now.

Comment: @pelms please post that as an answer